# Angular Component - strange rendering issue

Tags: angular, chromium

**Edit: does not happen on Firefox ESR.**

As you can see by the GIF, I have a strange rendering issue for the Material Table, under (inside) a Material Tab.

[image]

You can see the space is actually "allocated" for the element, but the row cells do not render immediatly.
But the weird thing is that if I keep the Developer Toolbar open, it works fine!

You'll also see the row are inputted using an `async` pipe on a `BehaviourSubject`. If I `delay(1000)` the `next` call, the row appears.

The expandable row (the main `div`, basically), is rebuilt every time it is opened, as it uses an `*ngIf` expression.

Parent component:

```
@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    ...
})
export class DetailSmartComponent {
    ...
    public readonly cronExpressions$ = new BehaviorSubject<List<CronExpressionModel>>([])

    @Input('model')
    public set modelInit(model: Model) {
        this.model = model
        const cronExprControl = model.getFormGroup().controls.cronExpressions

        this.toModels(cronExprControl.value).subscribe(this.setCronExpressionModels)

        if (this.lastSubscription) {
            this.lastSubscription.unsubscribe()
        }

        this.lastSubscription =
            cronExprControl.valueChanges.pipe(
                filter(cronExprs => !!cronExprs),
                switchMap(cronExprs => this.toModels(cronExprs))
            ).subscribe(cronExprs => this.setCronExpressionModels(cronExprs))
    }

    /** Last subscription, for when the input model changes. */
    private lastSubscription: Subscription

    private readonly toModels =
        (cronExpressions: List<string>): Observable<List<CronExpressionModel>> =>
            from(cronExpressions).pipe(
                mergeMap(c => this.invokeCronService(c)),
                toArray()
            )

    private readonly invokeCronService = (cron: string) =>
        this.jobService.describeCron(cron).pipe(
            catchError(() => of(Result.error('', 'Couldn\'t retrieve description'))),
            map(result => result.get()),
            map((description): CronExpressionModel => ({ cron, description }))
        )

    private readonly setCronExpressionModels =
        (cronExpressions: List<CronExpressionModel>) =>
            this.cronExpressions$.next(cronExpressions.slice().sort(asc))

    ...
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-tab-group">
    <mat-tab label="Cron">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <cron-expressions
                [isDisabled]="model.isDisabled"
                [cronExpressions]="cronExpressions$ | async"
                (removeCronExpression)="onRemoveCronExpression($event)"
            ></cron-expressions>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    ...
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cron-expressions',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    ...
})
export class CronExpressionsDumbComponent {
    public readonly displayedColumns = [...]

    @Input()
    public isDisabled: boolean

    @Input()
    public cronExpressions: List<CronExpressionModel>

    @Output()
    public readonly removeCronExpression = new EventEmitter<string>(true)
}

export interface CronExpressionModel {
    cron: string
    description: string
}
```

Template:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="cronExpressions">
  ...
</table>
```